# Argument 2: cannot convert from 'bool' to 'System.DateTime?'

Tags: c#, linq, type-conversion

I try to make a data range between two dates: Begin and End.

And for that I have the following query:

```
public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

private IQueryable<Alert> GetAlerts(int organisationId, DateTime? beginDate = null, DateTime? endDate = null,  bool includeDone = false)
{
    var query = 
        _patientDbContext.Alerts
            .Where(i => i.OrganisationId == organisationId && i.CreatedAt = endDate.ToString() <= beginDate.ToString());

    if (!includeDone)
    {
       query = query.Where(i => !i.IsDone);
    }

    query = query.OrderBy(i => i.Deadline);

    return query;
}
```

but I get this error:

> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'bool' to 'System.DateTime?'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `i.CreatedAt = endDate.ToString()` is an **assignemtn**, no **comparison**. Is this intended or a typo? I assume it´s intended, which would make your `Where` having a really annoying side-effect.

Comment: this is wrong on so many levels `i.CreatedAt = endDate.ToString() <= beginDate.ToString()` 1.CreatedAt is prooblay boolean and endDate.ToString() is string 
2.. i think you meant == and not =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation you are doing on CreatedAt is wrong. Change it as follows.

```
var query = _patientDbContext.Alerts
            .Where(i => i.OrganisationId == organisationId && (i.CreatedAt < endDate &&  i.CreatedAt > beginDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have an assignement (the `=` symbol) in your `Where` clause

```
i.CreatedAt = endDate.ToString() <= beginDate.ToString()
```

What you want to do is this, supposing `CreatedAt` is a `DateTime`:

```
var query = _patientDbContext.Alerts.Where(i =>
    i.OrganisationId == organisationId &&
    (beginDate == null || i.CreatedAt => beginDate.Value) &&
    (endDate == null || i.CreatedAt <= endDate.Value)
);
```